# How to create a thread safe method in django

Tags: python, django, multithreading, python-3.x, http

I am using django 1.10.2 with python 3.5.2 in a Linux machine.

I have 2 questions that are related:

1. What is spawn when a client connect to django? Is it a new thread for every client or a new process for every client?
2. I need to have a method in django that must only be accessed by the client one at a time. Basically this must be a thread safe method with perhaps a lock mechanism. How do I accomplish this in django.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your method do, and what are your concerns regarding thread-safety?

Answer (score 0):

1. It depends on how you deploy Django app. See Gunicorn or Uwsgi. Usually, there is a pool of processes.
2. Maybe db transaction could help you.

Comment: Good point, I use uwsgi.

Db transaction does not work for me.

Any other idea how to thread safe a method?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could try:

```
from threading import Lock
```

create lock with a broad scope

```
lock = Lock()
```

then to use:

```
with lock:
    //do stuff
```